# Synonyms for term/terminal/term-mode and ansi-term

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

`term` and `terminal` had verbatim identical tag wikis, so they clearly are intended to be used as synonyms. I think `term-mode` is also a synonym, as I can't think of a situation where a question would apply to `term` but not `term-mode`, or vice-versa.

Accordingly, I've recommended all three of these be merged under `term`.

Is `ansi-term` sufficiently distinct from `term` to warrant maintaining a separate tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done!  Everything points to `term` now.  I think `ansi-term` is probably distinct enough to keep it separate, but do not have strong feelings on the matter.